# Multithreading attempt in c++- is it doing what I want?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I have attempted to make a thread pool - I have a list of data samples i want to run a function on each sample. I want to invoke all threads in order to make the total time take to process all samples quicker. The idea being each sample is done on a different thread, the thread is chosen from the thread pool first on just Event_1-->thread_1 and then once all threads are used it finds the next available thread and uses that....at least thats the plan....

It seems to run but i dont get much change in the total time taken to run over all my samples. I am not expecting time per sample to improve but surely the total time should? Have I done something wrong?

I currently have this thread pool function:

```
class ThreadPool {
private:
  class ThreadPooler {

  private:
    int n_id;
    ThreadPool *n_pool;

  public:
    ThreadPooler(ThreadPool *pool, const int id) : n_pool(pool), n_id(id) {}

     void operator()() {
      std::function<void()> func;
      bool dequeued;
      while (!n_pool->shutdown) {
        {
          std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(n_pool->n_conditional_mutex);
          if (n_pool->queue.empty()) {
            n_pool->n_conditional_lock.wait(lock);
          }
          dequeued = n_pool->queue.dequeue(func);
        }
        if (dequeued) {
          func();
        }
      }
    }
  };


public:
  bool shutdown; 
  std::vector<std::thread> n_threads;
  std::mutex n_conditional_mutex;
  std::condition_variable n_conditional_lock;
  Queue<std::function<void()>> queue;
  ThreadPool(const int N_threads) : n_threads(std::vector<std::thread>(N_threads)), shutdown(false) {}

  ThreadPool(const ThreadPool &) = delete;
  ThreadPool(ThreadPool &&) = delete;

  ThreadPool & operator=(const ThreadPool &) = delete;
  ThreadPool & operator=(ThreadPool &&) = delete;

  void InitThreadPool() {
    cout<<"Initializing "<<n_threads.size()<<" threads "<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_threads.size(); ++i) {
      n_threads[i] = std::thread(ThreadPooler(this, i));
    }
  }
  void ShutdownThreadPool() {
    shutdown = true;
    n_conditional_lock.notify_all();
    cout<<"Shutting Down "<<n_threads.size()<<" threads "<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_threads.size(); ++i) {
      if(n_threads[i].joinable()) {
        n_threads[i].join();
      }
    }
  }

  template<typename F, typename...Args> 
  auto SubmitToThreadPool(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {

    std::function<decltype(f(args...))()> func = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...); //wrapper

    auto task_ptr = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()>>(func);
    std::function<void()> wrapper_func = [task_ptr]() {
      (*task_ptr)(); 
    };

    queue.enqueue(wrapper_func);

    n_conditional_lock.notify_one();

    return task_ptr->get_future();
  }
}; //end thread pooler
```

There is also a queue wrapper of the form:

```
template <typename T>
class Queue {
private:
  std::queue<T> i_queue;
  std::mutex mtx;
public:
  Queue() {}
 ~Queue() {}

  bool empty() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    return i_queue.empty();
  }

  int size() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    return i_queue.size();
  }

  void enqueue(T& t) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    i_queue.push(t);
  }

  bool dequeue(T& t) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    if (i_queue.empty()) {
      return false;
    }
    t = std::move(i_queue.front());
    i_queue.pop();
    return true;
  }
};
```

I run this in my main code like:

```
ThreadPool Pool(N_THREADS);
  Pool.InitThreadPool();
  auto startT0 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
  for(unsigned s=0; s<DataList.size()-1; s++){//
    std::future<void> Future = Pool.SubmitToThreadPool(GetDMWPulses, s, DataList[s], time_info,writefile, factor);
    Future.get();

  }//end s
  Pool.ShutdownThreadPool();
  auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(stop - startT0);
```

This is the DMWPulses function:

```
void GetDMWPulses(int s, STMDataPacket  DataList,  bool time_info, bool writefile, float factor){

    unsigned int nDigits = DataList.datasample.channel[0].ADCList.size();
    STMDataProduct pulse;
    vector<float>  hist,A, MWD, T;

    hist.assign(nDigits,0);
    A.assign(nDigits,0);
    MWD.assign(nDigits,0);
    T.assign(nDigits,0);

    for(unsigned j=1;j<nDigits-1; j++){      

           hist[j] =(DataList.datasample.channel[0].ADCList[j]);

    } 
     for(unsigned n=1;n<nDigits-1; n++){   
          A[n]= ((hist[n]-factor*hist[n-1]+A[n-1])); 

     }
     for(unsigned k = m+2; k < nDigits-2; k++){
      MWD[k]=((A[k]-A[k-m]));  

     }
     for(unsigned h = m+l+2; h< nDigits-2; h++){ 
       for (unsigned p = h-l-1; p <h-2 ; p++){ 
            T[h] += ((MWD[p]))/l;              
   }
       if(writefile){outputTfile<<" "<<T[h]<<" "<<"\n";}
     }

   float maximum_height = *std::max_element(T.begin(), T.end());
   int maxElementIndex = std::max_element(T.begin(),T.end()) - T.begin();
   float peak_time = DataList.datasample.channel[0].ADCList.at(maxElementIndex);
   pulse.SetPulseTime(peak_time) ;
   pulse.SetPulseHeight(maximum_height);
   pulses.push_back(pulse);

      hist.clear();
      A.clear();
      MWD.clear();
      T.clear(); 

    }//End Algorithim Function
```

Comment: Without seeing `GetDMWPulses` it's impossible to tell you whether multithreading should improve things (assuming your code is correct, which I haven't verified yet). It could be saturating the DRAM bandwidth on a single thread, who knows?

Comment: The function used there doesnt seem to matter- I tried a much simpler version with: std::future<void> Future = Pool.SubmitToThreadPool(printer,s); where , //Tester function for threading:
void printer (int id) {
  if (id%100){
  cout << "sample " << id << '\n';
}
} It also did not decrease significanlt the total time taken

Comment: Well in that `printer` test each thread has essentially no work at all. If your workloads are too small to benefit from threading in the first place, a thread pool is unlikely to help. It's also not clear what time you are comparing against - the serial time or a different parallel implementation? (Also, please don't add code in comments, [edit] the question instead!)

Comment: Ok thanks for advice- i have added the DMWpulses function for completeness

Comment: The time I am comparing against is the difference between the start and end times now added around the main function call

Comment: Off the bat, you have a data race on `ThreadPool::shutdown` - one thread is reading a non-atomic variable that another thread is writing to, with no synchronization.

Comment: Your `Queue` class template has a classic bug: It tries to synchronize each and every function call, which is both useless and sends the wrong message. Consider `empty()` for example. You call that function but you don't have a clues from the result whether the queue is now empty or not, because it was unlocked and any other thread might have modified it since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Future.get()` blocks until the packaged task is completed. You only call `SubmitToThreadPool` for the next sample after the previous sample is fully processed. There is no parallelism at all, everything is done sequentially.

Comment: this is what i feared. When i removed that line i get a seg fault, i'm a complete novice when it comes to threading. I'm not sure where else to put the return function.....I already have a get in the submit function but even with that i got a seg fault until i added ".get" in the "s" loop....but that clearly is not doing what i want....any advice on where it should "get" the future?

Comment: You need to store all those `future`s somewhere (e.g. in a `std::vector`), then call `get` on them in a separate loop, after you submitted all the tasks to the pool. Also, it's unclear why you are implementing your own thread pool to begin with - can't you just use [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)?

Comment: I tried creating a std::vector<std::future<void>> in ThreadPooler. This futures vector was filled before the last line of the submit function with the same as what is returned by that funciton. I then tried to loop through that vector and "get" the futures in the main code. It fills the futures for a few 1000 sampls but then produces this output *** Error in `./a.out': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f4cc0022c30 ***
1060
*** Error in `./a.out': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f4cb8000900 ***
*** Error in `./a.out': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f4ca8000900 ***

Comment: It sounds like you are adding to the vector in one thread, and reading from that same vector in another; a data race. Where does `ThreadPooler` even get those futures from? I don't understand at all what you are doing.

Comment: I chose to build the threadpooler as I wanted to initiate a given number of threads was advised that this was the best way to do that. The async looks useful but i dont know how you specify how many threads to use and make sure it uses all of those efficiently. The future is just the output of the SubmitToThread function.

Comment: In the code shown, `ThreadPooler` doesn't have access to the return value of `SubmitToThread` function, so it's unclear how it could put such return values into a vector.